# Getting lines from files with specific extension

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to get a couple of specific lines from files with a specific extension (.pvc).  These files are stored in different directories.  Then I want to put all the lines in a single txt file.

eg.

```
directory1/file_a.pvc
directory2/file_b.pvc
. 
.
directory100/file_x.pvc
```

I am trying to use the following `for` loop but it doesn't work.

```
for i in {1..5}
do
 echo $i
 cd /home/directory"$i"
 grep -e L1 -e L2 /*.pvc > /home/all_lines.txt
done
```

Comment: `grep -h 'L1|L2' ~/directory{1..5}/*.pvc >~/all_lines.txt`

Comment: In your attempt you are overwriting `all_lines.txt` in each loop (if you have write pemissions in `/home` at all). Use `>>` instead of `>` to append instead.

Comment: @Sato Katsura, By using the option -h I don't get nothing in the output file, but using -e L1 -e L2 it works but it also prints (in the output file) the path of the directories in each line.

Comment: `-h` tells `grep` not to print filenames.  This works with at least GNU `grep` and BSD `grep`.

Comment: It already works, I used -h along with -e. Thanks!

Comment: @Sato Katsura, Since I am pretty new in this forum I don't know how to mark your answer as the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer as requested:

```
grep -h 'L1|L2' ~/directory{1..5}/*.pvc >~/all_lines.txt
```

`-h` tells `grep` not to print filenames, `L1|L2` searches for lines `L1` and `L2`, and `directory{1..5}` expands to `directory1`, ..., `directory5`.

Answer (score 0):

Are they all sub-directories inside a specific directory (father_directory)?

You can try:

```
find /father_directory -iname '*pvc' -exec grep -e L1 -e L2 {} \; > /home/all_lines.txt
```

or, as suggested by @Philippos (thank you):

```
grep -r /father_directory -e L1 -e L2 --include "*.pvc" > /home/all_lines.txt
```

Comment: Or even simpler with `grep` only: `grep -r /father_directory -e L1 -e L2 --include "*.pvc" > /home/all_lines.txt`

Comment: They are into into sub-folders that in turns are into a common directory (I guess that would be the father_directory).